# Getting the type pointed to a pointer with reflection

Tags: reflection, go

Given this :

```
var v reflect.Value = ...

v.Type() // *model.Company
```

How to instantiate a new model.Company and modify its fields with reflection ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along the lines of:

```
v := reflect.ValueOf(&Company{})
t := v.Type()
c := reflect.New(t.Elem()).Elem()
c.FieldByName("Name").SetString("Reflection Inc.")
fmt.Printf("%#v\n", c.Interface())
// => main.Company{Name:"Reflection Inc."}
```

Working version in the playground:

- http://play.golang.org/p/YOs27t1vtA

Comment: You guys on SO are constantly saving my day. Hope I will be able to give back something one day.. By the way, it works like a charm; thanks Gustavo.